# Why is the output signal greater than the input signal in this voltage follower circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, non-inverting

I have implemented this circuit on my breadboard.
The voltage waveform at point A and B in the circuit attached below should be equal because it's a voltage follower, but in my case, after implementing on the breadboard I am getting higher output voltage (Point B) than the input voltage (Point A).
I have also attached the input waveform and the output waveform.

Can anyone tell me why this phenomenon is happening?

[image: Circuit]

[image: Input voltage waveform]

[image: Output voltage waveform]

[image: Bread board image]

Comment: Why is the input signal so noisy?

Comment: why is the signal so noisy?  are you sure this is the right signal? are you sure the scope is on the right settings (no voltage magnifier for eg)? i suggest showing us  your breadboard setup since this is such a simple circuit

Comment: Are you sure you attached the probe(s) correctly? As other pointed out, signals are too noisy for a 1Vpp signal.

Comment: I think the noisy signal because of the breadboard, and you can see the oscilloscope probes are connected correctly

Comment: Both Oscilloscope wires are connected at the same terminal.

Comment: You have invalid measurements using a Precision, Low Noise, CMOS, Rail-to-Rail,
Input/Output Operational Amplifiers by neglecting layout rules for good performance which nullifies an valid readings.  Reduce all wire to a <1cm with a tight layout and use twist pair if not possible. then filter all supply noise with appropriate RC filters.  This layout appears to be N.G.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: OP is doing things at 1kHz. While the layout is ugly it shouldn't matter at these frequencies

Comment: U might think so but if the injected noise is greater than the signal BW, the feedback can get attenuated resulting in gain

Answer (score 3):

The AD8606 is intended for a supply range from 2.7 volts to 5.5 volts and has a maximum supply voltage of 6 volts. According to your circuit, you are feeding it with +/- 3.5 volt supplies and this means the power supply is 7 volts: -

[image]

I'm not surprised that strange things may occur with such disregard for the data sheet.

You also indicate a 0.1 uF input capacitor yet, your breadboard shows an electrolytic AND, it appears that R1 is in series with the input signal instead of acting as a light pull-down: -

[image]

So, no bias on pin 3 and busting the absolute max ratings doesn't bode well for testing the AD8606.

I also don't see any supply decoupling capacitors. Typically 100 nF from each supply to GND are required for stable operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed the supply voltage to +/- 2.7 and remove the resistor and capacitor at the input. now I just connect the input signal at pin 3 but the same problem I am facing.

Comment: Your device may be damaged now that you exceeded the AMR. Plus, if you have made circuit changes then edit your question with a new section (after the original parts) showing the new circuit and the new breadboard picture and please try and format the picture so it is in the correct orientation.